# Linkedin Login using REST service and Javascript to store tokens

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to develop a sample app that uses Javascript in client side and consumes rest web services. I am new to LinkedIn ans social network APIs. Si I want to setup a LinkedIn login at first then other social networks later.

Linkedin API utilise OAuth2. I want to use it to store tokens that give us if the user authorize the application to access some its basic data.

I am thinking to use the REST API so the could request token for authorized users and stores them in a database via the developed RESTful web servcie. I know but we want to use what we have now.

[image]

The schema up tells what I have in mind. If I am wrong please help.

An other problem for is that I want to use token to renew it or get some data from social networks.

Comment: If you have a back-end web service, why not allow it to make the OAuth calls rather than insist the client does it via JS?

Getting a LinkedIn token server-side is well documented here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Comment: At this moment, I don't know how to do, I mean which suggestion should I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario might have one serious security issue - in case you do not use https for the step 3, the access token is not safe.

You are trying to use wrong scenario for the case. OpenID Connect (OAuth2 extension) among other defines following authentication scenarios:

1. Implicit flow - what you are doing with the steps #1 and #2. Login is completely done by a client and access token is returned directly to it by the means of the "#" URL part. The "#" URL part is not sent to the server and is secure even if your pages are loaded via http.
2. Authorization code flow is a 2 step process where client initiates login to get authorization code (which is valid once) and then exchanges it to access token on the server side. Access tokens should not leave the server side.

Authorization code flow also defines refresh tokens which could be stored in your DB and used to fetch new access tokens once they expire.